# Relation between Heisenberg and Schrodinger states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, time-evolution, quantum-states

I feel like I am a bit confused on the Schrodinger and Heisenberg pictures of QM. The following is a reasoning I thought of to derive a result that I found on my textbooks (see end), but I am unsure whether or not it is valid. I'd like to know if there's anything wrong with it, from notational issues to conceptual ones.

Consider the instantaneous position eigenstate $\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H$ in the Heisenberg picture. It obeys $$\hat{X}(t=t_0)\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H=x_0\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H\quad\quad\quad(1)$$ where $\hat{X}$ is the position operator. It evolves in time according to $$\hat{X}(t)=\hat{U}^\dagger(t)\hat{X}\hat{U}(t)\quad\quad\quad(2)$$ where $\hat{U}=\exp(-i\hat{H}t/\hbar)$ for a time-independent Hamiltonian. Substituting (2) into (1) gives $$\hat{U}^\dagger(t_0)\hat{X}\hat{U}(t_0)\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H=x_0\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H$$ Multiplying by $\hat{U}(t_0)$ gives, since $\hat{U}$ is unitary, $$\hat{X}\hat{U}(t_0)\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H=x_0\hat{U}(t_0)\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H\quad\quad\quad(3)$$ In the Schrodinger picture, we have that $$\hat{X}\left|x(t_0)\right\rangle_S=x_0\left|x(t_0)\right\rangle_S$$
Comparing this with (3), I get that, at $t=t_0$, $$\left|x(t_0)\right\rangle_S=\hat{U}(t_0)\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H\quad\Rightarrow\quad\left|x_0,t_0\right\rangle_H=\hat{U}^\dagger(t_0)\left|x_0(t_0)\right\rangle_S=\exp(i\hat{H}t_0/\hbar)\left|x_0(t_0)\right\rangle_S$$

I know this last result is correct, but I could not find any derivation for it, so I came up with the above. It seems simple enough but I keep getting confused between the two pictures so I believe I might have gotten something horribly wrong and/or that one of the steps above doesn't make sense.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526008/2451

Comment: A point to be noted is that $\hat X$ commutes with $\hat U$  only at $t_0$ if either $t_0 =0$ or $\hat U = \text{exp}(-iH(t-t_0))$

Comment: Instead of abusing latex by inserting a bunch of quad spaces, you should use \tag{#} to generate equation numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want $X$ have eigenvalue $x_0$ at $t_0$ you should take either $t_0=0$ or take $U(t)= \exp\{-iH(t-t_0)\}$ so that $U(t)={\rm Id}$ at $t=t_0$.